# inject one provider in other in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to calculate square and cube of number by using providers. My first provider is `mtProvider` in which I've declared four functions and in other provider `calService`, I declared two functions in which I am using the functions of `mtProvider` provider.

I want to use functions of `mtProvider` in `calService`.

```
 angular.module("myApps", [])
.provider("mtProvider", function()
{
return{
    $get : function()
    {
        return{
            add : function(a, b){
                return a+b;
            },
            substract : function(a, b){
                return a-b;
            },
            multiply : function(a, b){
                return a*b;
            },
            divide : function(a, b){
                return a / b;   
            }
        };  
    }
};
})
  .provider("calService",['mtProvider',function(mtProvider)
  {
   return{
       $get : function()
       {
          return{
              square : function(a)
              {
                  return mtProvider.multiply(a, a);
              },
              cube : function(a)
              {
                    return mtProvider.multiply(a, mtProvider.multiply(a, a));
              }
        }   
    };
}
}])
  .controller("myController", function($scope, calService){
   $scope.squareNumber = function()
   {
        $scope.answer = calService.square($scope.number);
    }
   $scope.cubeNumber = function()
   {
     $scope.answer = calService.cube($scope.number);
   }
 });
```

Comment: You are injecting `mtProvider`, but in your code you are calling the methods on `mathProvider`. That obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Now also its not working. I simply want to know how to use functions of one provider in another.